# Using data.table syntax to update column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table DT with 2 columns: ID, QTY

```
     ID        QTY
    000001       0
    000002       1
    000002       2
    000004       0
    000005       1
    000006       2
```

I want to update the Qty column for those rows where Qty is greater than 1 and replace the corresponding Qty value with 1.
This is a trivial task that can be performed by using sapply or simply using which command on the column. 
But I want to know if this can be achieved using the data.table[i,j,by/keyby,.SD] options.

Expected Output:

```
     ID        QTY
    000001       0
    000002       1
    000002       1
    000004       0
    000005       1
    000006       1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this by converting the logical vector to binary with `as.integer`

```
DT[, QTY := as.integer(QTY>0)]
DT
#   ID QTY
#1:  1   0
#2:  2   1
#3:  2   1
#4:  4   0
#5:  5   1
#6:  6   1
```

Or specify it in the `i` and update the 'QTY'

```
DT[QTY>0, QTY := 1]
```

Comment: does this operator ":=" has a special name? I could not find it in the vignette for introduction to data.table.

Comment: @Tushar It is the assignment operator

Comment: @DavidArenburg Will check this out too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DavidArenburg the link is broken.

Comment: @Emman https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html